# How to pick out certain terms in Applescript?

Tags: applescript

This is my current code:

```
tell application "System Events"

    set accounts to get the properties of every user

end tell
```

This code will return the properties of all the accounts. How would I make Applescript check for a specific account name?

So lets say one name of an account is Bob. How would I check to see if one of the account names is Bob?

Answer (score 0):

Named objects, including users, can be mentioned by name: `type "Name"`. So, to check if a user "Bob" existed, you could use the expression `exists user "Bob"` in a block addressed at System Events. Or, to get the properties of such a user, given that one existed, you could:

```
tell application "System Events" to get the properties of user "Bob"
```